# Python overriding classmethod in children

Tags: python-3.6

I am writing a simplistic ORM that would require me to override the methods inside the child classes. Depending on the context, I am either expecting to access the model through the class methods, or through the instance methods, therefore I can not simply override them. I believe this code describes the question well enough:

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def key_fn(cls, id):
        raise NotImplementedError('')

    @classmethod
    def load_all(cls):
        yield from db_fetch_prefix(cls.key_fn('')):

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def key_fn(cls, id):
        return f'/keys/{id}'

# how do I make sure B.key_fn is called here?
B.load_all()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `B.key_fn` would be called indeed. But your `load_all` returns a generator, because you let it `yield from db_fetch_prefix`. You can check this by running  `print(B.load_all())` at the end. The output will be:

```
python .\clsss.py
<generator object A.load_all at 0x0521A330>
```

I don't know what you want to achieve by using `yield from`. But an example that shows overriding of classmethods in subclasses is possible would be:

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def key_fn(cls, id):
        raise NotImplementedError('')

    @classmethod
    def load_all(cls):
        return cls.key_fn('foo')

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def key_fn(cls, id):
        return f'/keys/{id}'

print(B.load_all())  # prints "/keys/foo"
```

Guessing wildly that you want to apply the `key_fn` to each item yielded by your generator `db_fetch_prefix` (abbreviated to `fetch` below), the code below shows `B.key_fn` will be used in the presence of generators as well.

```
def fetch(callback):
    for i in range(5):  # fake DB fetch
        yield callback(i)

class A:
    @classmethod
    def key_fn(cls, id):
        raise NotImplementedError('')

    @classmethod
    def load_all(cls):
        yield from fetch(cls.key_fn)

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def key_fn(cls, id):
        return f'/keys/{id}'

print(list(B.load_all()))  # prints ['/keys/0', '/keys/1', '/keys/2', '/keys/3', '/keys/4']
```

Comment: My class B had been inheriting from NamedTuple, which discards any of the base classes in it's metaclass, so key_fn of A had never been called. I'll mark you question as the helpful one as it did indeed help me realise this!